# Wordpress submenu is blank

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

I've been willing to add a submenu to an existing plugin (school project), except that i can see it in the menu, but anytime i open it the page is empty.

Anyone know why it might does this?

```
static function admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page(
            _x( 'Foyer', 'plugin name in admin menu', 'foyer' ),
            _x( 'Foyer', 'plugin name in admin menu', 'foyer' ),
            'edit_posts',
            'foyer',
            array(),
            'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
            31
        );
        add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        'Foyer Settings', //page title
        'Settings', //menu title
        'edit_plugins', //capability,
        'foyer-settings',//menu slug
        'my_custom_submenu_page_content'//callback function
    );
    }
    
    function my_custom_submenu_page_content() {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
            echo '<h2>Page Title</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: I notice the `static` keyword, is your function inside a class? If so, you need to replace your callback argument with `array("class_name", "my_custom_submenu_page_content")` or make it an anonymous function like `function(){/*submenu_page_content*/}`.

Comment: Good to hear that! ;)